# Unabe to format SDCard with Disks (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-formatting

I have an 8GB sdcard which was used to extend the storage on my android phone. It now is not detectable on android or windows.
Ubuntu shows it but unable to format or delete partitions, I have tried the solutions from the other questions.

Here's the output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 321960E8-BABE-4EF1-907A-84F301351CAA

Device         Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1  2048    34815    32768   16M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p2 34816 15523806 15488991  7.4G unknown
```

Disks and gpart say operation successful when I try to format or delete partitions
But it doesn't reflect, just shows the partition as unknown

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm9CH.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob5CN.png

I've tried variations of the dd command

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=2048 count=32
32+0 records in
32+0 records out
65536 bytes (66 kB, 64 KiB) copied, 0.311052 s, 211 kB/s

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0p2 bs=2048 count=32
32+0 records in
32+0 records out
65536 bytes (66 kB, 64 KiB) copied, 0.000156408 s, 419 MB/s

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=2048 count=32
32+0 records in
32+0 records out
65536 bytes (66 kB, 64 KiB) copied, 26.9264 s, 2.4 kB/s
```

Kindly suggest if there is a way to delete this pesky partition or if this is a lost cause and the sdcard is not salvageable.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 321960E8-BABE-4EF1-907A-84F301351CAA

Device         Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1  2048    34815    32768   16M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p2 34816 15523806 15488991  7.4G unknown

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 1

Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 2
Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 321960E8-BABE-4EF1-907A-84F301351CAA

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 321960E8-BABE-4EF1-907A-84F301351CAA

Device         Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1  2048    34815    32768   16M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p2 34816 15523806 15488991  7.4G unknown

Command (m for help):
```

Comment: You should know that whole SD card is /dev/mmcblk0. The /dev/mmcblk0p1 is a partition. It may be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question

Comment: I solved the similar problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1478086/849328